# My attempt at creating a csv is not returning the correct data, what did I do wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my attempt to create a downloadable csv of some data, I followed [this railscast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

I have an admin page for the User mode, located in views/admin/users.html.erb

In my admin controller I have:

```
def users
@users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv {send_data @users.to_csv}
  format.xls {send_data @users.to_csv(col_sep: "\t")}
end
end
```

In my User model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << ["First Name","Last Name","Street","City","State","Zip","Company Name","Company Phone","Company Street","Company City","Company State","Company Zip","Deals Viewed","Deals Clicked Invest On","Deals Invested In","Amount Invested in Hedge Funds","Amount Invested in PPM"]
  all.each do |user|
    csv << [user.first_name, user.last_name, user.p_street, user.p_city, user.p_state, user.p_zip, user.c_name, user.c_phone, user.c_street, user.c_city, user.c_state, user.c_zip, user.clicks.count, user.investments.where(:status => "Interested").count, user.u.investments.where(:status => "Invested").count, user.amount_invested_2, user.amount_invested_3]
  end
end
end
```

And I added require 'csv' to application.rb.

However, when I go to admin/users.csv and download the document I just get 1 row of entries like this '#User:0x851d030', rather than the data I want. Where did I screw up?

Comment: the `to_csv` method is not returning the csv array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't screw up. You followed the railscast and it just happened to not work for you. I ran into the same issue.

I looked in the "Comments" tab to see if others had the same problem. And at least one person did. (Post: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=comments#comment_160703)

In short, you need to change:

`format.csv {send_data @users.to_csv}` to instead be
`format.csv {send_data User.to_csv}`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for the answer, it probably would have taken me far to long to catch that.

Comment: You're welcome! I've had to peruse the comments sections on at least a couple screencasts to find out where I went wrong. Good luck.